# Can someone explain what xml is?

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml

Sheshank S. just recently told me a solution for my question. I took it for granted, not knowing what it meant. Can someone explain all of this to me?
I have looked at all sorts of different types of tutorials (website, videos, etc...) but none of them explain what this means:

```
    xmlhttp.open('GET', 'https://api.scratch.mit.edu/users/oreyelephant', true);
```

And:

```
console.log(response["profile"]["bio"])
```

The reason I want to do this is to make a simulator that tells you specific tweets or comments containing something. With the code up above, I want to replace `["profile"]["bio"]` with the username, since all websites's classes and id's names are different.

Now I have this:

```
var username = prompt("Username Bio?");
    const xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open('GET', 'https://api.github.com/' + username, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            var response = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            console.log(response.username);
        }

        if  (xmlhttp.status == 404) {
            console.log("ERROR 404: File not found")
        }
    };
```

It still shows up with this error:

[image: My error]

Comment: nothing in your question mentions `XHTML`. `XHTML` has nothing to do with the `XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: What exactly are you asking about? The tags say XHTML, the title says XML, but your question body is about [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest), which you could simply read the documentation of. Those are three completely different technologies. For your _other_ question, we’d need more details about how you “want to replace `["profile"]["bio"]` with the username”. What is the desired result, what is the current result of your latest attempt?

Comment: The definitions of the _three different_ technologies you mentioned are here, at their tag descriptions: [XHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xhtml/info), [XML](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xml/info), [XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xmlhttprequest/info).

Comment: scratch.mit.edu has the name of the variable of your profile "profile". I think Github and Twitter, Facebook etc. have different names of the variables, since the creators had different preferences on what the name of the variable of your profile is. What I'm trying to figure out is how to find what the name of the variable that holds all of your profile properties is on any website that has profile pages. The reason I can't use "["profile"]["bio"]" for every website is because it gives me an error that I'll give an image of in my edit in a second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question name states "Can someone explain what **xml** is"

The tags includes the tag **xhtml**.

The question content based on my answer to your previous question is based on **XMLHttpRequests**

These three are three different things. I'm assuming you want details about **XMLHttpRequests**

In this case it takes the text from [https://api.scratch.mit.edu/users/oreyelephant][1]

[1]: https://api.scratch.mit.edu/users/oreyelephant and get's it in `response.text`

You then need to do `JSON.parse()` on it to parse out the Javascript object from the text. Then you can access the values like you would with normal objects `response.username` `response.id` etc.

Comment: The title was edited, originally it asked about `XHTML`.

Comment: What if I wanted a bio detector for something like Twitter or Github? (So sorry if you feel like I'm wasting your time, I'm 12 and I have a small brain capacity. Feel free to walk away.)

Comment: @Orey Then you would use the twitter or github api

Comment: @Orey this should help you https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference for twitter. if it helped remember to upvote the post and mark as correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Basically your code downloads whatever is at `https://api.scratch.mit.edu/users/oreyelephant`. Currently its this JSON:

```
{
    "id": 14457076,
    "username": "oreyelephant",
    "history": {
        "joined": "2016-01-18T18:34:50.000Z"
    },
    "profile": {
        "id": 13622297,
        "images": {
            "90x90": "https://cdn2.scratch.mit.edu/get_image/user/14457076_90x90.png?v=",
            "60x60": "https://cdn2.scratch.mit.edu/get_image/user/14457076_60x60.png?v=",
            "55x55": "https://cdn2.scratch.mit.edu/get_image/user/14457076_55x55.png?v=",
            "50x50": "https://cdn2.scratch.mit.edu/get_image/user/14457076_50x50.png?v=",
            "32x32": "https://cdn2.scratch.mit.edu/get_image/user/14457076_32x32.png?v="
        },
        "status": "ATTENTION: I now do art. It is a 200-follower special. :D\n\nNext vector art: 2 days\nI'm trying to release these kinds of things weekly.",
        "bio": "IMPORTANT-ish: Please check out @fight99 He/she uses Scratch in a creative ways that I've never seen!\n\nMale | 12 | Bryan\nJust your average middle-schooler trying to get by. You can call me Bryan. :D",
        "country": "United States"
    }
}
```

then parses this JSON with `JSON.parse`. The result is a Javascript object.
`response["profile"]["bio"]` is identical to `response.profile.bio` and basically gets whats under the `profile` object under `bio`. This is then printed to the console (`with console.log`).

So this will be printed to the console:

> IMPORTANT-ish: Please check out @fight99 He/she uses Scratch in a creative ways that I've never seen!\n\nMale | 12 | Bryan\nJust your average middle-schooler trying to get by. You can call me Bryan. :D

You can use do `console.log(response.username)` instead of `console.log(response["profile"]["bio"])` to print the username.

Comment: This is very helpful! Follow up question: What do I replace JSON.parse with if the specified profile wasn't made with JSON? Otherwise, perfect explanation.

Comment: With a parser that can parse your data. kind of depends on your data.

Comment: What if I wanted a bio detector for something like Twitter or Github? (So sorry if you feel like I'm wasting your time, I'm 12 and I have a small brain capacity. Feel free to walk away.)

Comment: then either they have a public API, then you read the specification, or they don't, then you can reverse-engineer what they're doing and act accordingly. Github [has an API](https://developer.github.com/v3/). Read it and understand it if you want to use it.

Comment: I updated my problem (for github)

Comment: @Orey Create a new question, you can't edit the question and make a whole new question.